# Replace for entire line produces duplicate occurrence of replacement text

Tags: .net, regex, powershell

Simple question: why does

```
"x" -replace ".*", "y"
```

produce "yy" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
"x" -replace ".*", "y"
```

is the equivalent of

```
[Regex]::replace("x",".*","y")
```

The result `yy` that you see is based on how this works, as per MSDN:

> Within a specified input string, replaces **all strings** that match a
>   specified regular expression with a specified replacement string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx

The replace will find a string that matches the regular expression and replace it with the given replacement. Hence, the x replaced with y and then empty string is replaced with y and you get `yy`.

This can be verified by doing `[Regex]::matches("x",".*")` - it give two matches - one for empty string and one for x.

In terms of other regular expression engines, this happens because of the `g` or the global flag.

This can also be verified in Python as follows ( just to show that this is not limited to Powershell / .Net ):

```
>>> re.findall(".*","x")
['x', '']
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you match two times, `*` matches first the entire string since it's greedy. And then it matches nothing. Thanks to @Tim for his comment.

What you should use is `.+`.

Comment: I think it *first* matches the `x` (because it's greedy) and *then* the empty string at the end of the line (because it's optional). And I do think that this is undesired behavior. I don't know any other regex engine that works like this. Usually, when a regex has consumed the entire string, the engine stops.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Yes it's the other way around :). But I can reproduce the results with various regex flavors. So maybe it's intented to be like this?

Comment: Another suggestion: If for some reason you need to use `.*`, you can achieve the correct behavior by anchoring the regex: `"x" -replace "^.*", "y"`