# Ant propertyregex behaving strangely

Tags: regex, ant, properties

I have the following:

```
<propertyregex property="myProp" input="${someInput}"
               regexp="(.*)" 
               replace="-f -d '\1'"
               override="true"/>
```

The intention of the propertyregex is to take the value of someInput and put it within single qoutes and prepend it with the -f and -d flags. 
If I set someInput to myString, the result that I expect would be:

```
-f -d 'myString'
```

but i get:

```
-f -d 'myString'-f -d ''
```

Can anyone explain where the trailing -f -d '' comes from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex matches twice. Once it matches the entire string, and then it matches the empty string at the end of the string (since the asterisk allows zero-length matches).

Use

```
<propertyregex property="myProp" input="${someInput}"
               regexp="^.*" 
               replace="-f -d '\0'"
               override="true"/>
```

(`\0` contains the entire match, so you also don't need the capturing parentheses).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322066/replace-for-entire-line-produces-duplicate-occurrence-of-replacement-text/8322388#comment10258765_8322388).